# What is upload_queue_size parameter in Logstash S3 output plugin?

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash, logstash-configuration

S3 output plugin of logstash has a config parameter called `upload_queue_size`. The documentation says: "Number of items we can keep in the local queue before uploading them". Which queue it is talking about here? and what are benefits/impacts of increasing this parameter?

Here is the link to the docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-s3.html#plugins-outputs-s3-upload_queue_size

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-s3/blob/e2e48eb647f5f6ad4a976baf399b59e6547a3b16/lib/logstash/outputs/s3.rb) of the plugin, this queue is storing the documents before sending them to s3. But I don't know what impact changing this value would have.

Comment: The plugin stores data in local temp files and based on its `rotation_strategy` it uploads them to S3. So, is this a queuing mechanism before storing in local files?

Comment: It looks like it is `max_queue` filed in `Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor` which is used to upload a file. Basically if the queue reaches its limit and there is no worker thread to upload a file, it uses its fallback policy which is to upload the file using the current thread.